# Next without for error userform Excel VBA error with Else-If Statement

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement, userform

**I am getting a "Next without For" error which I don't understand.**

I have a UserForm with 2 TextBoxes and 1 ComboBox:
[image: UserformPictureLabeled]

When I click *Submit* button, I want to check if the serial number matches existing data in column 4. In this case, I want the data to fill in the disposition column (3 rows to the right) with text from ComboBox1.

If it does match I want to fill a brand new row.

If no disposition is inputted, I want to exit the sub or message box. Either is ok.

I tried re-arranging `If`, `Else`, `For`, `Next` but nothing seems to work.

```
  Private Sub SubmitButton_Click()

  Dim serial_ID As String
  serial_ID = Trim(SN_TextBox1.Text)
  DispValue = ComboBox1.Value

  Worksheets("RMA Tracker").Activate
  lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row

  For i = 2 To lastrow
 

   'Searches for matching RMA & SN 'this assigns data to Log Sheet, if the data is brand new

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value <> serial_ID Then
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = RMA_TextBox1.Value
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4) = SN_TextBox1.Value
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = ComboBox1.Value


        Else
    
   'this assigns data to disposition column to matching entries in serial number column

         If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = serial_ID Then
         ComboBox1.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value


         Else
   
   
         If DispValue = "" Then
         Exit Sub
  

         End If

 Next i

 'this clears the fields of userform when button is clicked and saves it automatically
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
 Call resetform


  End Sub
```

Comment: try selecting all the code, then press Shift+Tab until everything sits on the left margin - then select every line between `Sub` and `End Sub`, hit Tab; then select every line between `For` and `Next i`, and successively indent entire nested code blocks like this, until you eventually hit the inevitable "oh." and add the missing `End If`. The best way to avoid this compile error is to consistently close every block you open, as soon as it's opened: type `If {condition} Then<ENTER>`, follow it with `End If` immediately and *insert* the body (at +1 indent level) - that will never fail you =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Or install Rubberduck and use the auto indent feature :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a bit misleading. The problem are your `If` statements. You have three `If` statements, but only one `End If` statement. Since you also have two `Else` statements, I assume, you want an `If` / `ElseIf` structure. There are two ways to fix that.

1. Three separate IF statements (all three statements will be executed)

   ```
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value <> serial_ID Then
               ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = RMA_TextBox1.Value
               ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4) = SN_TextBox1.Value
               ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = ComboBox1.Value
            End if

       'this assigns data to disposition column to matching entries in serial number column

             If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = serial_ID Then
                 ComboBox1.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value
             End if

             If DispValue = "" Then
                Exit Sub
             End If
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can set up an `If` / `ElseIf` structure (if the first/second `If` statement is `True`, the subsequent `If` statements won't be reached and code execution will proceed after the `End If` statement - unless you reach `Exit Sub` of course) :

   ```
             If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value <> serial_ID Then
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1) = RMA_TextBox1.Value
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4) = SN_TextBox1.Value
                 ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 7) = ComboBox1.Value
             ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 4).Value = serial_ID Then
                 ComboBox1.Text = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value
             ElseIf DispValue = "" Then
                Exit Sub
             End If
   ```

Comment: This certainly did the trick and got rid of the error. Thank you very much! I tried both ways..